# Make it easy to find work-from-home/telecommuting jobs on Careers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Make it easy to search for contract work that can be done from home.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jobs you can do from the comfort of your own silk pyjamas and not leave the house are considered telecommuting jobs.

Check the box when doing your search to bring these up.

> ☑ Only show telecommute jobs

Comment: http://twitter.com/#!/marcgravell/status/63500298320216065