# Search Careers for Home-Office

Tags: support, jobs, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make it easy to find work-from-home/telecommuting jobs on Careers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93999/make-it-easy-to-find-from-home-works)

I would like to search Stack Overflow [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs) for jobs where I would be able to work from home. Maybe even from another country.

But if I type in "Home-Office" in the "where" search box I get an "Unknown location" showing all jobs.

How can I do that? Can this be included in the search box?